# STT works less well when another application has focus. How can I improve STT to work as part of the OS?

Tags: 18.04, python, focus, nice, speech-recognition

STT works less well when another application has focus.  How can I improve STT to work as part of the OS? My virtual assistant program can do things like move windows around, but it seems to work best when it has the systems focus.  When another application comes to the front, it works less will.  I've written this in python.  Can I decrease the nice level of the process from within Python 3, or is there a better way to keep this application active and listening?  Here's a link to the application, but I don't expect anyone to look at it.  https://github.com/MikeyBeez/Juliet
I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3 in a conda virtual environment, and I'm running the GNOME DE.